# Play framework handle Future[Action]

Tags: scala, playframework

Hy!

I have 2 controller function whose are returns an Action. I have an another controller which is choose between these controllers sth like:

```
def replace(i: Int, s:String): EssentialAction = ???
def asd: EssentialAction = {
    if(true){
      replace(5,"asd")
    } else {
      replace(6,"asd")
    }
}
```

But when this controller is use a db func I get sth like:

```
def asd: Future[EssentialAction] = {
  Future(true).map{ bool =>
    if(bool){
      replace(5,"asd")
    } else {
      replace(6,"asd")
    }
  }
}
```

But the router can't handle Future[EssentialAction] :(

How can I rewrap the Future[Action] to just an Action inside a controller?

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

@Singleton
class TestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit
  val mat: Materializer) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index = Action.async { request =>
    asd.flatMap(_.apply(request).run())
  }

  def replace(i: Int, s:String): EssentialAction = ???

  def asd: Future[EssentialAction] = {
    Future(true).map{ bool =>
      if(bool){
        replace(5,"asd")
      } else {
        replace(6,"asd")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That .run() at the end... I was sooo close :D Thanks!

Comment: not working as expected need some more verification... Some of my tests failed after this modification :(